# How can play PCM Data in ios

Tags: ios, pcm

I have text change to  ultrasonic the file.
I get PCM data for the file.
The PCM data info:

- @sample   PCM data buffer
- List item
- @sample_len  PCM data size: sizeof(sample)
- @channel_num  1
- @samprate   44100
- @word_len   16
- List item

But I don't know play PCM Data in iOS.

Please help me